# Why do I get val.slice is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, slice

I am implementing a web-app with **express** using **three-layered architecture**. I have **blogposts** as a resource stored in **mysql** database. This is how the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS blogposts (
    blogId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    posted VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    imageFile VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    userId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT blog_id PRIMARY KEY (blogId),
    CONSTRAINT id_fk FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES accounts(personId)
);
```

Now I want to retrieve a blogpost id sp I send queries to the database in the *data-access layer* and export the function like this:

```
exports.getBlogpostId = function(blogId ,callback){

    const query = "SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE blogId = ?"
    const value = [blogId]
    db.query(query, value, function(error, blogpost){
        if(error){
            callback("DatabaseError", null)
        }else{
            callback(null, blogpost)
        }
    })
}
```

Then I use it in my *business-logic layer*:

```
exports.getBlogpostId = function(callback){
    blogRepo.getBlogpostId(function(blogpost, error){
        callback(error, blogpost)
    })
}
```

Then finally I use it in the *presentation layer*:

```
router.get("/:blogId", function(request, response){

    const blogId = request.params.blogId
    blogManager.getBlogpostId(blogId, function(error, blogpost){

        const model = {
            error: error,
            blogpost: blogpost[0]
        }
        response.render("blogpost.hbs", model)
    })
})
```

When I try to retrieve the id I get the following error:

```
TypeError: val.slice is not a function
      at escapeString (/web-app/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:202:23)
      at Object.escape (/web-app/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:56:21)
      at Object.format (/web-app/node_modules/sqlstring/lib/SqlString.js:100:19)
      at Connection.format (/web-app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:271:20)
      at Connection.query (/web-app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:189:22)
      at Object.exports.getBlogpostId (/web-app/src/dal/blog-repository.js:19:8)
      at Object.exports.getBlogpostId (/web-app/src/bll/blog-manager.js:12:14)
      at /web-app/src/pl/routers/blogRouter/blogRouter.router.js:39:17
      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/web-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      at next (/web-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

I do not call the slice method anywhere, so I do not know why this error occur?

**EDIT:**
Found the problem, I had forgot to add blogId as a parameter in the business-logic layer!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see slice in your included code examples?

Comment: That's the thing I don't use it anywhere...?@evolutionxbox

Answer (score 1):

looking at the error ths error come from the module `sqlstring` and the most local thing is from `/web-app/src/pl/routers/blogRouter/blogRouter.router.js:39:17` so you will have to look at it here

Comment: what is at the line ?

Comment: blogManager.getBlogpostId(blogId, function(errors, blogpost)
Which will call the function in the business-logic layer

Comment: try converting your blogId from a string to a number

Comment: Found the problem now, I forgot to add blogId as a parameter in the business-logic layer function. Thanks for answering.